# Confusion about what this matrix multiplication in a Markov chains question means

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuyKY.png

I have this thing that I think is a multiplication,a 1xn probability distribution multiplied by an nxn transition matrix for a markov chains question. If tM=t then isn't M just the identity matrix? Unless this is not a multiplication but then I'm just even more confused

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UPnC.png

This is the rest of the question that I'm pretty stuck on if anyone can help

Comment: Could you maybe shortly summarize the question, without the links to online images? $tM=t$ doesn't mean that $M$ is the identity matrix, in general.

Comment: Yeah it's just I can't do the formatting so I tend to just like images. Suppose a Markov system has transition probability matrix
M, and suppose there is a probability distribution t such
that tM = t. Let A be the square matrix each of whose
rows is the vector t, and let B = M − A. Prove that
AB = BA = 0 and A^2 = A. Hence find an expression for
M^n. This is the question in full if it helps

Comment: This link may be helpful.. also for the future https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If M isn't the identity matrix then I'm just confused as to how you could multiply t and M and get t?

Comment: For example, $(1,0) \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} = (1,0)$. It's a lot of questions, do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have that t = (t_1,t_2....t_n) and I know that A is an n x n matrix with t as it's rows. I know B = (M-A) and I want to prove AB=BA=0 so I have AM-A^2 for AB and MA-A^2 for BA. I feel I'll be able to do these once I have a better understanding of M

Answer (score 0):

No more is needed then to substitute into the formulas.
$$
(A^2)_{ij}=\sum_k A_{ik} A_{kj} = \sum_k (t_k t_j)=(\sum_k t_k) t_j = t_j = A_{ij}
$$
That's one equality. What about the others?...

Comment: So after proving A^2 = A, I know that AB = AM-A^2 = AM-A and that BA = MA-A^2 = MA-A and I feel I can probably get something out of that, just need to prove AM = MA = A, which I guess is because tM=t?

Comment: @MattSimpson $AM=A$ because $\mathbf tM=\mathbf t$, but $MA=A$ because $M$ is row-stochastic. As was done above, write down an expression for the elements of these products using the definition of matrix multiplication and simplify.

Comment: Yep I've got this down, thanks for confirming it